# changes in Interface Building not showing up in app

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, interface-builder

I made some changes to my xcode4 app's main view; moved some buttons around, changed some titles;
ran it and saw all the changes.
Went back in, made some more changes, ran it; changes no longer show up.
Have done File > Save from Interface builder.
Have closed and reopened xcode4.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, xcode4, willy-nilly, created a directory "en.lproj" in my project and moved my .xib file there.

SOLUTION:
1. moved my .xib back to my project directory.
2. deleted en.lproj directory
3. rebuilt

works fine.

What happened??

Answer (score 0):

I think every xCode project creates that directory, and that is where it automatically places the .xib or the storyboard. At least that is the case for all my projects. Maybe it was just confused?